# How does Minecraft determine the spawn location in a seeded world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if there is any rhyme or reason behind where you spawn in SSP in Minecraft after seeding your world.

From my first hand experience, the answer is *yes* you always spawn with the same x,y co-ordinates on a seed. But I wondered when this came in, and whether what I've seen is backed up by anything (and not just circumstantial).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Minecraft Wiki article on Spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn) is a good start. Specifically;

> Every world has a "spawn point" (really, an area) located within a few hundred blocks of the origin (0x, 0y, 0z). This point is stored in the level.dat file's SpawnX, SpawnY, SpawnZ attributes (although SpawnY seems to be ignored). If the spawn point is deemed unacceptable, a new, temporary spawn point will be selected (although the criteria for "unacceptable" is unknown).

So you always spawn "somewhere" near the center of the map (0,0). Generally the game will try to spawn you on a sand tile near water (The "washed ashore" effect). So, if you always load the same seed, then the algorithm should always plop you down in the same spot that is "close to" the center of the map.

The rules for multiplayer are somewhat different however, and the article is worth the read on that aspect.

Comment: What I've found though is I've spawned in a swamp near water, on the exact same block, every time. I've not seen the behaviour you describe, or the wiki describes.

Comment: This has changed since the wiki was last updated (when the new biomes were added I think). The sand tile near water thing is definitely no longer true.

Comment: Ok so the above post is no longer true?

Comment: i have been spawned in a different spot before but because an animal was where I normally spawn when I seed that map. usually it is fairly close to the original spawn point but sometimes it is disorienting.

Answer (score 3):

I've actually tested this... unless I wrote my seed numbers down wrong you do not always spawn in the same area. I deleted a world I had been work on for a while because I got frustrated with it. When I created the world again I haven't been able to find the village I used last time I played this seed is no where near where I've been spawning and when I first played this seed it was VERY close to my spawn point. So no, this is no longer true. It's also happened with 5 other seeds.

Comment: Which version of Minecraft?

Comment: Well quite of bit of Minecraft's seed generation code is based on PRNGs (Psuedo Random Number Generators) . I too have reused seeds from 1.7.10 maps and have ended up in completely different areas than I was before. From what I understand the seed numbers are used to control how wild the PRNGs go with the random numbers. So in one way or another you are never guaranteed the same "experience twice"