# Multiple games linked to one world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

## Background

I like to restart a lot when I play minecraft; and I rarely play online. I am the kind of player who will start a game, get established, explore, and then get bored and start again. However, I like the idea of starting all my new games in the same world.

I found that if I replace the 'region' folder in one save folder with a symbolic link (or a 'shortcut' in windows) to the region folder of another save, then they both save to the same location, and changes in one game are reflected in the other; but world generation anomalies tend to occur, due to multiple different seeds being used depending on which game is used.

Further, I found that if I linked two games with the same seed (e.g. one that was re-created from the other), then each would act like its own game, as above, but without the problem of world generation bugs. The only downsides seem to be that I have to start and respawn in the same location each time (the global spawn for that seed), and that it is tedious to set up each time I restart.

Additional notes: the 'linked' games allow for individual games to occur as if they are different users on the same server; they have different coordinates, inventories, and ender chest contents, but the world is the same.

## To the Question

I would like to be able to start new games in (ideally a new location in) a  pre-existing world, while having the old game still usable. If there is some kind of mod or third-party package which I can install to automate this for me, that would be really cool. If not, if anyone else has tried and succeeded at this, I'd like to hear your solutions.

Comment: seems impossible to use the same map and make the spawn different according to this [post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-does-minecraft-determine-the-spawn-location-in-a-seeded-world), as the spawn is always calculated to be near the center of the map, so if the map still the same, spawn will likely be at the same place as before

Comment: @Pronox, I think a mod could change the spawn point to a random coordinate. Not exactly change where the 0,0,0 is located.

Comment: I mean you could just get the seed then do `/spawnpoint 99999 75 99999 @s` then `/kill @s`

Comment: The allure for me to be in the same world, is occasionally running into things I've made in previous runs (though that wasn't clear in my question); but combining that with a linking solution definitely seems like it would solve the worldspawn and seed issues (assuming setspawn is per-player not per-world)

Comment: you could build a datapack with a function that uses /spreadplayers and then /setworldspawn then whenever you want to restart just drag in the datapack or you could even make a program to check when a new folder is created in saves folder (idk how) and then link and copy datapack with that, i'm just not sure if this already exists or if you'd have to make it yourself

Answer (score -1):

You could change the global spawn point via `/setworldspawn` but I have a feeling that is not what you mean, so I'll have to dive into this myself and see what I can do.